# Proving feasibility and unfeasibility

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, linear-programming

I want to show or prove the following statement:

Suppose that some problem $P_M$ is unbounded. If problem $P$ is feasible, then it is unbounded.

My gut tells me to prove the contrapositive, namely that if $P_M$ is bounded, then if $P$ is feasible, it is bounded.

However I feel that I am just traveling in circles, and not grasping something I should potentially be.

Would someone be able to give intuition to if I should be perusing the proof in this manor some other. Any and all advice welcome.

Edit: I am not looking for the solution, as [it is given here on page 99](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxg286/Math484_V1.pdf), rather an explanation

Comment: what is the relationship between $P$ and $P_M$?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling to understand. I copied this word for word, my professor doesn't speak English well... But it's under my assumption $P$ is the solution space to $P_M$, at least, that's what I'm assuming. Sorry I should've mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Without a clear relationship we can't say much. Do you have any other context? This sounds almost like a duality theorem.